# private key flash drive for server login

Tags: login, console, authentication, key-authentication

is there a way to make it so with my servers when I want to get into the console I can just plug in a flash drive with private keys on them that are trusted like the ones I have for ssh from my computers?

and how would I be able to use this flash drive to ssh into my server on a new computer that I dont feel like looking up my password on lastpass on?

is this a "safe" way to be able to get into a server if lets say I disable password login and only have ssh login?

Comment: Yes you can do that, and also keys should always be used for production servers, and password login disabled. You are on the right track. I will write up an answer for your `ssh` problem in a bit, if isn't answered already.[Hint](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)

Comment: I find the question confusing. "ssh login": do you mean using local console, but "autologin" (user and "password") when you put the right USB token?